# Does Frieza have God Ki?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 25th, Golden Frieza power can be felt by Tenshinhan, who says his power is amazing, something that couldn't happen if Golden Frieza would have God Ki, because God Ki can't be felt by those who can't use God Ki. But at the same time, Golden Freezer says that based in the energy he can feel from Super Saiyan Blue Goku, he can say he's clearly superior (to Goku), something he couldn't do if he didn't have God Ki, because only people with God Ki can feel other people's God Ki.

So, my question is, does Frieza have God Ki or not?

Comment: is it possible to sense non God Ki in someone who has God Ki because then this sounds very much like when Frieza and his men used scouters and kept getting surprised by increases in power because of power concealment, in this case Frieza is assuming that the only power Goku has is Normal Ki when he actually had God Ki being concealed in a way

Comment: @memor-x . I'm not sure about that . Why Piccolo and the others couldnt sense Beerus regular ki then? Besides this video seems to imply that when you dont leak your ki, you are using god ki, and "you dont alert your opponents" , in the sense their ki can't be sensed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xz-i1QnOmWc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer your main question, Does Freiza have God ki? **The answer would be No**. However, only **God Ki people can feel other people's ki is incorrect**.

God ki is mainly perfect ki control. You could compare it to something that happened back in dragon ball where they were capable of masking their ki and used to power up while engaging in battle with a foe. This is a much more complex version of the same where Goku and Vegeta have mastered energy control.

While Goku is in the God transformation, since Frieza couldn't **directly sense his energy,** we see him strike Goku in his final form and tells him that he was gauging his power. Even after he turns to Golden Freiza, Freiza could feel the pressure of Super Saiyan Ki and managed to gauge the difference in strength based on that.

Freiza is a very experienced fighter. He's also a fighting prodigy. So him assessing Goku's power based on the **Pressure** from SSJB, is not something impossible. Also, Freiza **wasn't able to gauge Goku's power exactly** both during their first fight and a later on fight. Goku initially was holding back against Golden Freiza, **(Not by a substantial amount. Also please note that Freiza was holding back as well)**. Freiza hence didn't use enough energy to destroy Goku when he had the chance. It was after Goku figured out the stamina drain that the two of them powered up to full power. During their second fight, Freiza was shocked when he realised **Goku in his SSJB state was as strong as Golden Freiza**. We see this by the expression on his face when the two of them exchange punches. When Goku fought Krillin and When Vegeta fought Future Trunks, they both stated that they could feel an immense amount of pressure even if they aren't able to sense the exact amount of energy.

Now take Caulifla and Kale during the tournament of power. Since they are neither aware of God ki and are very experienced as fighters, they were more startled by the Super Saiyan 3 transformation than any of the God transformations despite those being a lot Superior.

Finally, let us consider the mighty **Jiren the Gray**. We know Jiren doesn't have god ki as his energy is felt by all the other contestants. Yet, in the start, when Goku punched him in his SSJ forms, he didn't move. When Goku turned SSJG at struck him, how did he **detect the power of the transformation and raise his finger**? His experience as a fighter allowed him to sense how strong Goku was. Jiren was holding back immensely against SSJB Goku and even SSJB+ Kaioken*20 Goku. If Jiren couldn't sense Goku's energy, he probably would've sensed more energy from someone like **Maji Kayo** and attempted to punch Goku out using the force of his fist. Very experienced fighters can gauge the amount of power a user has while he or she is utilizing God Ki. We also know Goku only attains God ki during his SSJB and SSJG transformations. However, when Goku fought **Beerus in his base form aka(Monaka), **Goku said that his ki felt like Beerus's ki.

I believe utilizing God ki is a lot different from being able to sense it. God ki basically involves energy control where you mask your ki a lot. Even fighters who do not possess god ki can do the same. We see Hit doing the same initially during his fight with Vegeta and even his rematch with Goku. Even Jiren does the same until his fight with Goku as the Universe 6 Kaioshin was curious about Jiren's' power and wanted to Maji Kayo to help reveal the same. Even Goku knew he was strong but didn't know he was that strong as he was surprised with Jiren being able to push back SSJB+Kaioken * 20 and push back the spirit bomb effortlessly. Even the gods and Angels obviously can guage a fighters strength when god ki is being utilised. We see this based on Whis's suggestion that Goku and Vegeta would need to fight together to defeat Freiza and Vermouth suggesting that Jiren was a lot stronger than the SSJB transformation.

## Some Snaps of the events described earlier

[image: Krillin]

[image: Trunks]

[image: Vermouth]

**Pressure felt while facing off against SSJB:** I believe this can be compared to a scenario where a fighter is in the gravity chamber but doesn't know where he is. He feels this unmeasaurable force of power against him. On the other hand, when energy can be sensed, you can compare it to the fighter setting the level of gravity in the chamber and this would allow him to know how strong exactly his opponent(Which here is the gravity) is, and use sufficient amount of energy necessary.

Comment: yes, those statements about the pressure makes it confusing but I think they dont mean they feel their ki. I think they mean they feel some difference in the air, like a wind or something. Here there is more discussion about god ki not being felt by those who has regular ki. It states " Obviously, god ki can't be felt by those with only regular ki (e.g. Beerus can't be felt by Piccolo and others, but can be felt by Goku when in god form). " https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/7b16kh/god_ki_vs_regular_ki/

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to use God Ki to feel God ki. We know this based on Goku vs Monka(Where goku in his base form stated Monaka's ki was like Beerus's ki). Secondly, pressure doesn't mean the "Wind" lol.  I added a good analogy to my answer with regard to the same. Have a look at it.